# Get a YouTube playlistId in Android app from YouTube Data API v3

Tags: java, android, json, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to do what I thought would be a simple task in an Android application. I want to be able to start playback of a YouTube playlist, like this:

```
 String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLF3DFB800F05F551A";
 Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayPlaylistIntent(MainActivity.context, PLAYLIST_ID);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Obviously having a hardcoded `playlistId` isn't going to work. I want to be able to query with the YouTube Data API for a user's playlists and use one of those IDs. I have already registered my application using [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register), and I have what I believe to be a valid API key, as it works with the YouTube Player sample application. The setup for that is [described here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup).

Anyway, it seems to me at this point I should just be able to do an HTTP GET with parameters and specify my API key with the `&key=<key_here>` and I should be able to get some JSON data back that I can parse through. That's where I'm stuck.

I think I want to get a [collection of playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list), but I don't know how. What I've tried is an HTTP GET to this URL:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=id&key=<MY_API_KEY>
```

but I just get

```
{
    "error": {
     "errors": [
      {
       "domain": "usageLimits",
       "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
       "message": "Access Not Configured"
      }
     ],
     "code": 403,
     "message": "Access Not Configured"
    }
}
```

I know my API key is valid because it works with the sample application I mentioned above. What other configuration is needed to be able to start to query using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)? To me, the Google documentation for this is all over the place. Do I have to do something with OAuth?

How do I get my Android application to be able to start making simple calls via HTTP using the YouTube Data API?

Answer (score -1):

[YouTube Direct Lite for Android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android) will give you a great idea.

in [Dev Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) to play with Android YouTube player you should setup "Simple API access" for Android, to use Data API you should enable "installed application" as Android.

Comment: I have set everything up in the dev console properly. That example looks like it wants you to use a hardcoded playlistId that you set in `Constants.java`. What about programmatically retrieving that information from the Android app?

Comment: You can do that as well. My use case was different.

Comment: Right, but that was my question. I feel like I have the plumbing in place but I can't do a query and parse the JSON response.

Comment: Here is how I do queries, you don't need to parse JSON, just use the java library. https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java#L434